# How to convert 4 modbus registers (each 16 bit) to a double float in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion, double

I use libmodbus and have an array of 16 bit integers, where my modbus registers are saved. I tried with MODBUS_GET_INT64_FROM_INT16(mod_arr, 0), but the value is (of course) an integer. Usage of (double) before the MAKRO is not working.

modbus_get_float_dcba(mod_arr) read only 2 registers, not 4 registers.

Is there a function/macro for read 4 modbus registers as double (64 bit)?

Comment: Simplest would be to copy `uint64_t` over `double` with `memcpy(&dbl, &u64, sizeof dbl);`. But it's unclear from your question what the byte order of the modbus frame or your system is. You may need to do some bit shifting before the copy if order of bytes don't match.

Comment: It works. Thanks! 
I must swap the bytes before, but now it works. :-)

Comment: How about a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with a short sample code to demonstrate your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. :-) My solution is:

temp[0] = modbus[3];

temp[1] = modbus[2];

temp[2] = modbus[1];

temp[3] = modbus[0];

memcpy(&mb_double, &temp, 8);